# Typecsript conditional type with unknown

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, conditional-types

I was trying to correctly type following function:

```
function nullToUndefined(p: null): undefined;
function nullToUndefined<T extends Exclude<unknown, null>>(p: T): T;
function nullToUndefined<T extends Exclude<unknown, null>>(p: null | T): T | undefined
{
    return p === null ? undefined : p; 
}
```

It seems to be working fine for some cases:

```
const a = nullToUndefined(null); // undefined
const b = nullToUndefined(true); // true 
const c = nullToUndefined(10);   // 10
```

however it doesn't work for the following piece of code

```
const d = nullToUndefined(1 as number | null);
```

type of the variable d is `number | null` but i'd like to see `number | 
 undefined`. The problem seems to be in the `T extends Exclude<unknown, null>` - since unknown is a supertype of all types I would expect T to be everything except null, but obviously it doesn't work like this.

For example I can do

```
const e: Exclude<unknown, null> = null;
```

and TS compiler doesn't complain.

Is this behaviour expected or am I using unknown in an incorrect way? Is there any other way how to achieve correct typing for the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Exclude` you need to use your own conditional type to map `null` type to `undefined` one. Since conditional is executed on each member of the union type the code is quite straightforward. The only caveat that if you specify a return type of the function that is a conditional you have to cast the actual value:

```
type NullToUndefined<T> = T extends null ? undefined : T

function nullToUndefined<T>(p: T): NullToUndefined<T>
{
    return (p === null ? undefined : p) as NullToUndefined<T>; 
}

const d1 = nullToUndefined(null); // undefined
const d2 = nullToUndefined(1 as number | null); // number | undefined
```